# Parsing Google Weather On Android

Tags: android, android-xml

Hey I am trying to parse weather conditions from google. but all the time it gives me "error" message which I defined on try catch block.which I printed as an exception below.

I've debugged my app and find out

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
```

on that line my app goes to catch.but not really sure what is wrong.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        String c = city.getText().toString();
        String s = state.getText().toString();
        StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
        URL.append(c + "," + s);
        String fullUrl = URL.toString();

        try {
            URL website = new URL(fullUrl);

            // getting xml reader to parse data
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            XmlHandler doingWork = new XmlHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
            String information = doingWork.getInformation();
            tv.setText(information);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            tv.setText("error");
        }
```

XmlHandler.java

```
public class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private XmlData info = new XmlData();

    public String getInformation() {

        return info.dataToString();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equals("city")) {
            String city = attributes.getValue("data");
            info.setCity(city);
        } else if (localName.equals("temp_f")) {
            String t = attributes.getValue("data");
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(t);
            info.setTemp(temp);
        }
    }

}
```

XmlData.java

```
public class XmlData {

    int temp = 0;
    String city = null;

    public void setCity(String c) {
        city = c;
    }

    public void setTemp(int t) {
        temp = t;
    }

    public String dataToString() {
        return "In " + city + " The Current temp in F is" + temp + " degrees";
    }
}
```

Here is the LogCat

```
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=lincoln,nebraska
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:653)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at com.android.WeatherXMLParsing.onClick(WeatherXMLParsing.java:61)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-04 17:46:16.124: W/System.err(647):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-04 17:46:16.134: W/System.err(647):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You might want to print the exception in the catch block so that you can get an idea of what is happening

Comment: @Mus good idea :) I've done that and posted logcat logs :)

Comment: @Rodrane - I have some bad news, :S please review my answer below.

Comment: 1/ networkonuithread. 2/ excepction without stacktrace log. 3/ "lincoln,nebraska" should be urlencoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to report that the API has been removed a while back.

More information [here](http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/08/28/did-google-just-quietly-kill-private-weather-api/). It caused a bit of an upset at the time but after all it was a (very nice) **private** API... there was never any documentation or support for it.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to open that URL, I get this message

> We're sorry...
>
> ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To
>   protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

instead of getting an XML response. Make sure you get the appropriate API key (if any) so that the server doesn't return this response.